# VBA code that finds first row in column with integers and stores rownum as variable

Tags: vba

I know this is really simple but I am new to VBA and I really don't know what I am doing

```
Dim StartRow As Range
Dim Sht As Worksheet
Dim TotalRows As Long
Dim StartCell As Integer    

Set StartRow = Sht.Range("J7").End(xlDown)  'I just need to create a variable for the first
' row with numerical figures in column J and then use this as a starting point for my
' data in column D as well.
```

In the end I want VBA code that will select two ranges (one in column D and one in J) but where the starting point between the two will be the same, but it will be different across spreadsheets, hence the End(XlDown) function.  The range just needs to select all the data going down until it his the #N A N A signs.

Answer (score 0):

`range("j7:j100").SpecialCells(xlCellTypeConstants,xlnumbers).Cells(1,1).row`

Comment: Hi @Nathan, thanks for the help.  I wish to store this row number as a variable on it's own so that I can use it for the starting point in column D also.  And then create a variable for the end point of column J, which is basically the last integer in that column, and use these two variables to create a range for the values between startpoint and end point

Comment: You'll have a look at the properties of the specialcells, it returns a range, then look at the properties of a range, so `row` `cells.count` etc.