# Variable for RowNum of first and last integer in a column and creating a range between the 2

Tags: vba, excel

I want to create two variables, one for the row number of the first integer in column J  and one for the last integer in column J (after this there are many rows of #N A N A).  I then would like to use these two points to create a range for column J but also for column D (using the same variables) 
I just started using vba earlier this week, understand the simplicity and I have found similar answers elsewhere but none quite so specific.  Any help would be much appreciated.  What I have so far:

```
Dim StartRow As Integer
Dim sht As Worksheet
Dim LastRow As Integer
Dim JRange As Range
Dim DRange As Range

Set StartRow = Range("j7:j100").SpecialCells(xlCellTypeConstants, xlNumbers).Cells(1, 1).Row
LastNonRow = sht.Cells(sht.Rows.Count, 8).End(xlUp).Row (I fear this includes the #N A N A rows too)

Set JRange = sht.Range(StartRow,10,sht.Cells(LastRow,10))
Set DRange = sht.Range(StartRow,4,sht.Cells(LastRow,4))
```

Comment: ???? https://stackoverflow.com/questions/44410667/vba-code-that-finds-first-row-in-column-with-integers-and-stores-rownum-as-varia

Comment: aha sorry I am still confused!

Answer (score 0):

First, you should use:

```
Set JRange = sht.Range(sht.Cells(StartRow,10),sht.Cells(LastRow,10))
```

Second, don't use the `Set` keyword with `Integer` or other value types. The `Set` keyword is only for use with objects. If you are not familiar with object vs. value types, you should do some research on that. Here are some Excel VBA examples:

```
Dim i     As Integer
Dim j     As Double
dim str   as String
Dim coll  As Collection
dim sht   As Worksheet
dim rng   As Range

i = 1
j = 2.4
str = "This is a string of text, also a value type"
Set coll = ThisWorkbook.Sheets    'Note that ThisWorkbook.Sheets is a Collection
Set sht = coll(1)    'sets sht to the first Sheet in coll
Set rng = sht.Range("A1")
```

If you just care whether a number is in the cell and not necessarily an integer, you can do something like this

```
'Use Double instead of Integer because the possible range of values is larger. 
'This reduces risk of error
Dim LastRow     As Double  
Dim UpperLimit  As Double 

'Assuming you already have StartRow
LastRow = StartRow + 1

'Use UpperLimit to ensure you don't go into an infinite loop
'Set UpperLimit to an appropriately high value
UpperLimit = 100000

'Test Loop
Do While IsNumeric(sht.Cells(LastRow,10).Value) and LastRow <= UpperLimit
    LastRow = LastRow + 1
Loop

'Check if it exceeded upper limit
If LastRow > UpperLimit Then
    MsgBox "Exceeded Limit"
    Exit Sub
End If

LastRow = LastRow - 1    'Because the sht.Cells(LastRow,10).value is non-numeric

'Now set ranges
```

If you care whether it is actually an integer, you can use the above code, but put a conditional statement inside the loop to test whether the number is indeed an integer. There are many resources on the web that give code for determining whether value is an integer.

Also, you should make sure you set the `sht` variable before you use it.

```
Set sht = ThisWorkbook.Sheets(1)
```

Or

```
Set sht = ThisWorkbook.Sheets("MySheetName")
```

Hope this helps.

EDIT:
If the range is not continuous with integers, reverse the loop:

```
LastRow = UpperLimit
Do Until IsNumeric(sht.Cells(lastRow,10).Value)) Or LastRow = StartRow
    LastRow = LastRow - 1
Loop
```

If you do this, remove the `LastRow = LastRow-1` from the end of the code as the value you are looking for is already in LastRow.

Comment: The test loop will only find the last cell with a number in a continuous range, it will not find the last cell with a number in `Range("J7:J100")` if there are error or string values in between the first and last cell with a number.

Comment: Hi @JonWittmer thank you very much for the help.  I am still a tad confused as I will be using this macro on different workbooks and the StartRow will change depending on where the first integer is in that column (the column is likely to stay the same).  Would you be able to help me create a variable for this?

Comment: @RikSportel thank you, there are no error messages between the first and last integer

Comment: @Y.Ono Use the code you provided to find the StartRow each time you run the macro. Put that before the code I provided inside the same procedure.

Comment: @JonWittmer  the following line of code keeps on returning 'Application or Object Defined Error'
 'StartRow = Range("J7:J100").SpecialCells(xlCellTypeConstants, xlNumbers).Cells(1, 1).Row'

Comment: @Y.Ono That line works fine for me. Are you sure there is a cell with a number in the specified range? A less elegant solution would be to modify the original loop I gave you to look for the cell with a number in it.

Comment: There is a number but it starts from cell J45 onwards, However I won't the startcell across wrkbooks. @riksportel is this what you meant when you said it had to be a continuous range?

Answer (score 0):

There's a bunch of issues with your code:
`Set StartRow` - You only use `Set` when you're creating an object.
Also there's an issue with referencing the cells. There are a bunch of different ways to do this, I suggest to read up on this.

The following will take the first row with a number and the last row with a number, even if there are Non-number values in between. It will run on the currently active sheet.

```
Sub test()
Dim StartRow As Integer
Dim LastRow As Integer

Dim JRange As Range
Dim DRange As Range
Dim RangeForLoop As Range

StartRow = Range("J7:J100").SpecialCells(xlCellTypeConstants, xlNumbers).Cells(1, 1).Row
For Each RangeForLoop In Range("J7:J100").SpecialCells(xlCellTypeConstants, xlNumbers).Cells
    LastRow = RangeForLoop.Row
Next RangeForLoop

Set JRange = Range("J" & StartRow & ":J" & LastRow)
Set DRange = Range("D" & StartRow & ":D" & LastRow)

End Sub
```

Comment: Thank you for the help.  I will read up on what you suggested. I get "Application or object defined error" on the following line of code 

StartRow = Range("J7:J100").SpecialCells(xlCellTypeConstants, xlNumbers).Cells(1, 1).Row

Comment: many thanks for the help, for some reason that line of code still comes up with an error message.... not quite sure what is wrong with it

Comment: Do you actually have the sheet on which you wish to check column J activated when you run the code? And are there any numbers in range J7:J100? If there aren't any, you won't get anything returned and you'll receive an error.

Comment: Yes I have the sheet open and there are percentages in row J but not in all of the cells in the range J7:J100,  I just picked J7 as one of the first empty cells in column J to look down from to find the first integer

Comment: The code works when there is a value in J7. However I will not know which row the values start in over differing spreadsheets.  Is there anyway I can edit the code to take into account this.  I just need to find the first cell with a value in in row J.  In this case it is J45... but again, It will change.

Comment: Change the range to J:J

Comment: I still get the error message "application-defined or object defined error".  It works when I put a figure in J7 but as soon as I take it out it will not run. Strange!

Comment: Does it happen to be a 1004 error? If the macro doesn't find any cells of the specified type it will throw this error. Since it doesn't find any cells, it cannot set the `StartRow` variable. There needs to be at least one numeric value indeed. If there are cases in which this doesn't apply, you'd have to code around that.

Comment: Understood.  It is exactly a 1004 error.  However I do have integers in cells J46 - J245, so surely the code should still run seeing as I used "J:J"

Comment: I changed the code so I am not looping and so I can run through the code.  It seems as though the following line is the problem:   
     With .SeriesCollection.NewSeries
            .Values = JRange
            .XValues = DRange

Comment: That's a new question.